# Must I convert dataset to TFRecords for Google Cloud ML Engine?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-ml

Can I train my model in Google Cloud ML Engine without converting the dataset to TFRecords?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, according to [docs](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/concepts/data-prep):

> Cloud ML Engine doesn't get involved in your data format; **you can use**
>   **whatever input format is convenient for your training application.**
>   That said, you'll need to have your input data in a format that
>   TensorFlow can read. You also need to have your data in a location
>   that your Cloud ML Engine project can access. The simplest solution is
>   often to use a CSV file in a Google Cloud Storage bucket that your
>   Google Cloud project has access to. Some types of data, sparse vectors
>   and binary data for example, can be better represented using
>   TensorFlow's tf.train.Example format serialized in a TFRecords file.